# Gitlab CI/CD: Deploy to ubuntu server using ssh keys (using a windows shell runner)

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello everyone i need your help plz, i'm using gitlab ci/cd and trying to deploy my .jar application to an ubuntu server, i configured my gitlab project with a windows runner with shell executor. i configured a key based access on the runner to avoid being prompt for a password;

the following command runs successfully when i login to the runner machine and use it's powershell :

```
scp -i C:\Users\Administrators\ssh\id_rsa  myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar username@myubuntuserver:/
```

but when i'm using the above commande in my .yml file to copy the .jar on the server, it doesn't give any response until the job fail due to timeout

i tried also the solution proposed here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/  by setting an SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable on my project but i'm unable to adapt the given 'before_script' to my windows runner.

this is the before_script proposed in the documentation (above link):

```
 before_script: 
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )' 
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s) 
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - 
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

when the previous scp command is replaced by this:

```
ssh -iv C:\Users\Administrators\ssh\id_rsa username@myubuntuserver
```

i get the following output: 
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEQdp.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `username@myubuntuserver:/`? Does username has the right to write in the root folder of a server?

Comment: Yes it has the rights, but even when i try to copy to another folder the result is the same

Comment: Can you replace your scp command by, for testing, `ssh -iv C:\Users\Administrators\ssh\id_rsa  username@myubuntuserver` (no trailing slash), and edit your question with the output (only when run in GitLab-CI job)

Comment: I did and it seems to expect the part 'C:\Users\Administrators\ssh\id_rsa' to be the part containing the server address

Comment: What did you see as error message?

Comment: check the image (in my question) it says : 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname C:\\Users\\Administrators\\ssh\\id_rsa: No such host is known.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after doing the following steps:

1) configuring the runner (shell executor) on   ubuntu 18.04

2) Then from the terminal login as the gitlab-runner user: `sudo su - gitlab-runner`

3) run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

4) run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  username@myubuntuserver:`

5) run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@myubuntuserver "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod -R go= ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

5) now you can add the following to your job script (yml file) and it should work:

```
   - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa fileToCopy username@myubuntuserver:/mydirectory
     #you can execute multiple commands at a time, for ex: 
   - ssh username@myubuntuserver " mv /mydirectory/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /mydirectory/myapp.jar "
```

Hope it will help

Comment: No need: I will post an answer later

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh -iv C:\Users\Administrators\ssh\id_rsa username@myubuntuserver` does not work, that may be because of the `C:` part, which confuses ssh into thinkig C is the name of the server!

A Unix-like path would work:

```
ssh -iv /C/Users/Administrators/ssh/id_rsa username@myubuntuserver
```

But, as the [OP Medmahmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9239937/medmahmoud) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718648/gitlab-ci-cd-deploy-to-ubuntu-server-using-ssh-keys-using-a-windows-shell-runn#comment101949322_57718648), this supposes the public key has been published on the server:

> Configure the runner on ubuntu18.04.
>   Then from the terminal login as the gitlab-runner user:
>
> ```
> sudo su - gitlab-runner - run ssh-keygen -t rsa 
>   ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@myubuntuserver
>   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@myubuntuserver \
>       "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod -R go= ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
> ```
>
> Now from your yml file the following should work:
>
> ```
> - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa pom.xml username@myubuntuserver:/mydirectory
> ```